# I am writing a query in MongoDB . I have an Order table and i want to get future/upcoming orders of all products grouped by date here is my schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am using mongooseJs

```
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product:String,
    quantity:Number,
    date:{type:Date , default: Date.now},
    delivery_date:String,
    amount:Number,
    total:Number,
    payment_status:{type:Boolean,default:false},
    status:{type:String, default:"Placed"}, 
});
```

what i exactly want to do is display date wise upcoming orders 
i.e

today(Feb-1) :- Product A -- 100 units

(Feb-2) :- Product A -- 150 units , Product B -- 200 units

(Feb-3) :- Product A -- 20 units , Product B -- 400 units

(Feb-4) :- Product A -- 0 units , Product B -- 500 units  , Product C -- 5 units

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregate pipeline to group documents

1. `$match` - to filter all past dates
2. `$group` - to group by data and product, and $sum quantity for each product
3. `$sort` - to push into a sorted array
4. `$group` - to group products by date
5. `$addFields` - to map `_id.date` as `_id`

pipeline

```
db.orders.aggregate(
    [
        {$match : {date : {$gte : new Date()}}},
        {$group : {
            _id : {date : "$date", product : "$product"},
            quantity : {$sum : "$quantity"}
            }
        },
        {$sort : {"_id.product" : 1}},
        {$group : {
            _id : {date : "$_id.date"},
            products : {
                $push : {product : "$_id.product", quantity : "$quantity"}
                }
            }
        },
        {$addFields : {_id : "$_id.date"}}
    ]
)
```

Comment: what's not working? any errors or output not in expected format? can you post the sample document?